# Principles give pactitioners of the method added confidence OR Principles give TO pactitioners of the method added confidence

Tags: grammaticality

While speaking with a native speaker, she commented that I was constantly using the preposition TO in a wrong way. However, it was difficult for her to explain the rules of grammar that I was breaking. For her, it sounds awkward, period. She also commented that it was a very common mistake for Spanish speakers like me.
Since then I have been wandering on the internet but I have not found anything that could help me to understand my error in order to avoid it.

Here is a good example:
The right way: Principles give pactitioners of the method added confidence.
My (wrong) way: Principles give TO pactitioners of the method added confidence.

Could somebody please help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question really concerns the rules for direct and indirect objects, especially when the latter is placed in front of the former.

Take a simple example to begin with: **Peter gave Joan the book.**
(NOT **Peter gave TO Joan the book**.)
**The book** is the direct object (ask: gave what?)

It is customary to place the indirect object (**Joan**) (ask: to whom)
in front of the direct object **(book)** without a preposition.
That's the construction that most native English speakers generally use.

Another way of saying this is: **Peter gave the book to Joan.**
Here, when the direct object **(book)** precedes the indirect object (**Joan**)
the preposition **to** is required in front of **Joan**.

In your sentence, **added confidence** is the direct object (give what?).
 **Practitioners of the method** is the indirect object. (to whom?)
Your native speaker is right:
**Principles give practitioners of the method added confidence**.

So when you place the indirect object (**practitioners of the method**)
**behind the verb and in front of the direct object** (**added confidence**),
you **don't** use a preposition in front of the indirect object.(**practitioners of the method**)

But you do use a preposition when you place the direct object in front of the indirect object:
 **Principles give added confidence to practitioners of the method.**

There are numerous sites that give examples of this usage.
The following may be helpful.

https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/direct-and-indirect-objects  https://study.com/academy/lesson/the-difference-between-direct-indirect-objects-in-sentence-structure.html
https://www.espressoenglish.net/common-english-mistakes-with-direct-and-indirect-objects/

Comment: Thank you so much for answer.
It really helped me to understand my mistake and it is also nice to know that I have to study direct and indirect objects.
Truly useful.
Thanks again.